# label for Google pie chart is missing

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization, google-pie-chart

[Google Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoWAM.png)

I am using Google Pie Chart to display information but one label is missing, increasing height didn't work too.

Here is my code

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },

                       2]);

      var options = 
      {
        title: "",
    pieSliceText: "none",
    colors: ['#6f9643','#dcc591','#9487bf','#6f9693','#9d5434','#bfe1e0',
                '#a8c08e','#a89fca','#efbfbf','#9fc4d6','#eaaa7a','#dcc591'],
        bar: {groupWidth: "80%"},
        legend: {   
        position: "labeled", 
        textStyle:{bold:true, fontSize: 11}
        },
        height: 500,
        width: 900,
        chartArea:{width:'85%',height:'80%'},
    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
        is3D:true
      };
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the screenshot is included at the top

Comment: only thing that will help is increasing the size...

Comment: you know how I have straight lines for labels, can I have curvy lines instead? I have seen it on a website but I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: there are no options for styling the lines...

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
pieSliceText: "none"
```

to view label in slice of pie chart

More info [visit](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)